# Converting conditional with continue statement inside loop to NEON

Tags: ios, inline-assembly, neon

I've thought about how this would look in NEON intrinsics:

```
if (!(a > 1 && b > 1 && a < w-2 && b < h-2)) {
  ...
  continue;
}

// other operations
```

and I wonder if when `a` and `b` are 4-vectors this is actually possible to write.

1) Would I have to put a conditional for every operation that follows, checking if the possibly zeroed/invalid numbers don't have to be added to computation?

2) Would I lose the speed improvement that NEON intrinsics give me?

Comment: It seems that a and b are x and y coordinates getting checked whether they are within an image's size. And they most probably will be used as indexes. Values in NEON registers cannot be used as indexes. They have to be moved to ARM registers for that purpose, and it comes with terrible overheads. Better stay away from NEON for this particular routine.

Comment: You are correct, that's the use of `a` and `b`. Would GPGPU be better for speeding up calculation of residuals of projection in your opinion?

Comment: GPGPU scales even worse than NEON in cases like this. You should reconsider your algorithm. Do a and b have to be random upon each iteration? Is there no possibility accessing the pixels sequentially?

Comment: The transformation is ever changing, so the projected position will not allow for sequential memory reading.

Comment: In that case, the algorithm isn't SIMDable to start with.

Comment: I think a lot of computer vision algorithms that are seemingly trivial have to be rethinked if one wants to make them run at the fastest speed :)